# Add oauth2 support in nelmio sandboxes

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, fosrestbundle, nelmioapidocbundle

I'm working on a REST API in Symfony2 (created with FosRestBundle).

Before oauth was enabled I could try the API methods in the sandbox provided by [nelmio](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle).

Example:

```
GET /api/products/{id}.json
```

However now that oauth is enabled in order to call an API method I have to add the oauth token as a query string.

Example:

```
GET /api/products/{id}.json?access_token=ZWRhNTE2MGUzZWE4ZTIzNDIxMGUxNjZkY2Yx...
```

These api calls work outside nelmio without any problems.

In order to activate support for oauth in nelmio I've added the following config in `/app/config.yml`:

```
nelmio_api_doc: 
    sandbox:
        authentication:            
            name: access_token      
            delivery: http
            type:     bearer
```

After that it asks for an `api key` at the top of the screen, however if I set there the oauth token I still get an unauthorized response when trying to use the sandbox.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: try with the config `delivery: query`

Comment: Oterwise you can use the token setting it in the  filed: Header HTTP as follow: `Authorization= Bearer <access_token>`

Answer (score 3):

I also have a FOSRestBundle based API. I am not sure you need to force a name in the authentication block.

This config worked for me:

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    name: My awesome service
    sandbox:
        authentication:
            delivery: http
            type:     bearer
```